# Do prestige class levels count as cleric levels for domains?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, prestige-class, domains

I'm a cleric that will take the church inquisitor prestige class, but I am wondering if the church inquisitor levels will stack with my cleric levels for the Lust domain’s granted power, or if only my two cleric levels will count.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question, but it now dawns on me that I may have misunderstood. I assumed you were referring to the granted power of the Lust domain, but you may have meant that or the Lust domain’s spells or both. Please edit to fix my mistake if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Domain Granted Powers

#### Cleric Domains

Not by default. When domains specify “cleric level” and you get them through the cleric class, then they mean just your class levels in cleric. A prestige class that advances cleric spellcasting, like church inquisitor, does not count for domain granted powers, because

> He does not, however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have gained

Since your cleric level for domains is not caster level, spells per day, or spells known, this spellcasting feature does nothing for it.

A prestige class **can** say it counts as cleric levels for the purposes of domain granted abilities. Church inquisitor, however, does not do so.

#### “Extra Domains”

*Complete Divine* has a confusing section about “extra domains” that goes into great detail about how the domain spells work when the domain comes from a prestige class—how that affects clerics, how that affects other prepared spellcasters like druids, how that affects wizards specifically due to the spellbook, and how that affects spontaneous spellcasters. It addresses how those spells are still arcane for arcane spellcasters.

But on the subject of the granted power, it is quite brief:

> If a noncleric enters a prestige class that allows access to a domain, the character still gains access to the domain. She can use the granted power bestowed by the domain normally.

What does “normally” mean for a noncleric with a domain that references a nonexistent cleric level? No idea! The rules don’t say whether you’re supposed to pick a class, or use the same class you’re advancing the spellcasting of, or that you should just use your entire character level—any of these might make sense, but it doesn’t specify at all.

### Domain spells

Just in case there was some confusion here: as you continue to advance your cleric spellcasting, that includes gaining new domain spell slots from which you may prepare your domain spells.

Comment: +1, and if you know a working 3rd party solution or developed a working houserule, it might be good to add it here.

Comment: @Mołot “Solution”? What problem is to be solved? Advancing cleric level for the purposes of granted powers beyond your actual cleric level? I would suggest a feat à la Practiced Spellcaster, maybe, or just choosing domains more carefully—plenty of them don’t rely on cleric level at all.

Comment: *"What does “normally” mean for a noncleric with a domain that references a nonexistent cleric level?"* - for that problem.

Comment: @Mołot Oh, mm. I’ll have to give that some thought. My approach was always just picking other domains.